# Dynamic template URL in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have two different sidebar, and I want from a variable that I get back from the url, switch between two templateURL.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sidebar',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './sidebar.component.css'
    ]
})
```

I did this but i have a message erreur:

```
import {
  Compiler, Component, Injector, VERSION, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
  ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'sidebar',
    templateUrl: '<ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>',
    styleUrls: [
        './sidebar.component.css'
    ]
})

export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', {read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamicTemplate;
constructor(
private _compiler: Compiler,
        private _injector: Injector,
        private _m: NgModuleRef<any>
) {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
        let myTemplateUrl = './sidebar.component.html';

        if (this.modee === 'char') {
            myTemplateUrl = './Othersidebar.component.html';
        }
        const tmpCmp = Component({
            moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: myTemplateUrl
        })(class {
        });
        const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
        });

        this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
            .then((factories) => {
                const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
                const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
                cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
                this.dynamicTemplate.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
            });
    }
```

and thes is the error message :

```
client?afea:119 ..../app/sidebar.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './<ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>' in '.....\app\sidebar'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/sidebar/sidebar.component.ts 303:18-77
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/index.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main
```

is there a solution to that? and what is this error?
thx

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution :

```
templateUrl: '<ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>',
```

change temlateURL to template

but he dos not work

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a router guard with the sidebar template, and then switching based on route or URL. Sidebar Module with 2 different sidebars, and 2 routes for that module. Template1, Tempalte2.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
I did not understand what you mean ?